# XCode finished running application on phone

Tags: xcode

I can't debug any application on my iPhone. XCode compiles the application, deploys it to iPhone, says it is running the app, and immediately I see the message "Finished running x.app on iDevice". Although the app crashes, it is copied to the phone. After this crash I can start the application on the phone without problems but can't seem to debug any project on the phone. No old projects, no new projects, everything seems to be broken.

There are lots of advices to solve this problem on SO but none of them helped me a bit.

I use XCode 4.6 on Mac OSX 10.8.2.

Answer (score 0):

had the same problem when i changed the project name and the app name.
i've done several times reset to the simulator 'ios simulator' --> 'reset....'.
try it, also try to delete old app in device and simulator, do 'product' --> 'clean', and then  try again.

it sounds silly but its working for me when i has the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try changing the Version number in 'deployment target' in your App's target in XCode to something else.
2. Does it run in your Simulator?
3. Try running in some other device (some other device version,like 4S or 4)
4. Is the issue with iPad or iPhone or both?